# get property safely from an object in a node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, null, undefined, lodash

First a little bit of **context** (you can skip this part if you prefer to focus on code).

I joined a new project that will be integrated in a **nodeJS**'s platform. Our team does have experience with **JEE enterprise Web Apps**. That sets up our background. This new project will consume REST APIs, aggregate some data, implement some business logic and pass these data to front-end consumer. Sort of lightweight microservice architecture.

Some co-workers started to work on the project and I found it that in the source code we do have a lot of code snippet like `if (foo != null && foo.property != null) {return foo.property.value;}`

Foo being supposed to be an object passed as an argument to a function which would implement that kind of test.

A snippet example will talk more.

Let's pretend that's the response of an API i am consuming. I want to write a small function which would return `statusValue` if the object does exist, if it's not null or undefined, not empty and the property does exist and isn't blank or empty for instance.

```
var response = {
  "services":[],
  "metadata": {
    "status": "statusValue"
  }
};
```

That's how it is as for now :

```
function getStatusValue(response) {
    if (response != null && response.metadata != null) {
        return response.metadata.status;
    }
};
```

What would be considered as a best JS practise to implement that (we are also using lodash so maybe it's a better option to use lodash internals for that). I am just fearing we are transposing our Java habbits.

Basically i would like to know how to check for `null, undefined, empty, blank` safely (if that makes sense). What would be the JS best practice for that in 2016 with libraries such as lodash and stuff.

Comment: For one thing, you can leave out the `!= null` because `null`/`undefined` is falsey

Comment: I use `if (obj && obj.prop)`. To prevent `undefined` object you can use `strict mode`.

Comment: Yep we are using strict mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking for properties of an object, checking for loose equality to `null` is not enough.

Loose equality (`==`) employs type hinting in JavaScript, which attempts converting the members to a common type that can then be used for determining whether they are equal or not.
As such, best practices for JavaScript dictate that strict equality (`===`) is always to be used, in order to avoid edge-case scenarios or unknown behavior when checking for values or types.
You can find more info about loose vs strict equality here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

While this is not a must-have in your function, it is a good practice to follow and develop as a habit, so that on later code the implications of loose equality (`==`) could be avoided (e.g. avoiding `'3' == 3`, when a number or string type is expected).

Although considered a downside of the language by some, using `null` is similar in intent as checking for `undefined`, but is actually meant to express in the code that the coder is expecting an `object` (or lack of) to be provided, instead of a primitive type (`number`, `string`, `boolean`, `function`). This differs from Java, or any other typed language, where `null` is used for `Object` type defined variables; *but in JavaScript there's no constraining a variable to given type.*

You can find out more details about `null` at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

In practice, and especially when dealing with values that come outside of a unit - which is the case of any API - is considered a best practice to actually check for the type being an `object`, in order to make sure it **has** properties.

While your code is not incorrect, it does show that there's not much attention to best practices, which eventually will lead to writing buggy code.

My suggestion for your code, following best practices and independent of any library, is:

```
function getStatusValue(response) {
        // must be of type `object`, to have properties.
    if (typeof response === 'object' &&
        // any variable of type `object` might be `null`, so exclude that.
        response !== null &&
        // `metadata` property must be of type `object`, to have properties.
        typeof response.metadata !== 'object' &&
        // `metadata` is of type `object`, check for not being `null`.
        response.metadata !== null) {


              // `status` property is expected to be a string, given by the API spec
          if (typeof response.metadata.status === 'string' &&
              // on strings, we can access the `length` property to check if empty string (0 chars).
              response.metadata.status.length > 0) {
                // all good, return `status` property.
                return response.metadata.status;
          } else {
            // `status` property is either not a string, or an empty string ('').
          }


    } else {
      // invalid `response` object.
    }
}
```

Also, it might be easier to create or use from any libraries you integrate, a function to check for a valid object; something like [_.isObject](https://lodash.com/docs#isObject) or  this:

```
function isObject(o) {
  return (typeof o === 'object' && o !== null);
}
```

which you could later be used in the above snipped like so:

```
function getStatusValue(response) {
    if (isObject(response) && isObject(response.metadata)) {

          if (typeof response.metadata.status === 'string' &&
              response.metadata.status.length > 0) {
                return response.metadata.status;
          } else {
            // `status` property is either not a string, or an empty string ('').
          }
    } else {
      // invalid `response` object.
    }
}
```

As a final thought, as it is clearly visible, following best practices does increase the size of your code, but the benefit is that the resulting code is much safer, with less chances of throwing exceptions *(root of many app crashes)*, easier to collaborate on, and easier to build tests/coverage for.

Answer (score 0):

Using Lodash, you can use the `_.isNil(response)` function documented [here](https://lodash.com/docs#isNil).

In general, I would check a variable like this:

```
if (typeof x !== 'undefined' && x !== null) {
  // x has some value
}
```

You should *not* check whether `x === undefined` because if `x` *is* undefined, you'll get a dereference error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (more concise) way to do such a thing with just JS:

```
var obj = ...;
var val = obj && obj.prop && obj.prop.val;
```

`val` will be `undefined`/`null` if either `obj` or `obj.prop` are; otherwise it will be `obj.prop.val`.

This works because of the short-circuit evaluation of `&&`. It's literal behavior is this: if the first operand is falsey, it evaluates to the first operand. Otherwise, it evaluates to the second. This works as expected for booleans, but as you can see, it can be useful with objects.

`||` has similar behavior. For example, you can use it to get a value, or a default if the value is falsey (e.g. `null`):

```
var val2 = val || "not found";
```

Note that this would evaluate to `"not found"` if `val` is *anything falsey*, including `0` or `""`.

Comment: What if `obj.prop.val === false`?

Comment: Then `val` would be `false`.

Comment: Sometimes that check is not correct e.g. `obj.prop.val = 0`. But I also use that check :)

Comment: `&&` doesn't necessarily evaluate to a boolean; see my edit. Try typing `obj = {prop:{val:0}}; console.log(obj&&obj.prop&&obj.prop.val)` into your console.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this using the following function:

```js
var response = {
  "services":[],
  "metadata": {
    "status": "statusValue"
  }
};

function getStatusValue(res) {
  if (res && res.metadata) 
    return res.metadata.status || 'not found';
  else
    return 'not found';
}

console.log(getStatusValue(response));
```

The `if` statement will return `false` if `res` or `res.metadata` are `undefined` and if they both exist, it will return `res.metadata.status` *only if it's defined or `0`*, otherwise it'll return `'not found'`.

Comment: Note this would return `'not found'` if `res.metadata.status===0`

Comment: That's the solution I used as for now. i guess I will need to set up a test suite to see how it behave with all the kind of situations I can get

Answer (score 0):

No need to use any library you can use javascript's [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

From mdn web docs:

> The optional chaining (?.) operator accesses an object's property or calls a function. If the object accessed or function called using this operator is undefined or null, the expression short circuits and evaluates to undefined instead of throwing an error.

So instead of

```js
function getStatusValue(response) {
    if (response != null && response.metadata != null) {
        return response.metadata.status;
    }
};
....

let status = getStatusValue(response);
```

you could just use

```js
let status = response?.metadata?.status;
```